# How much does it cost for a visitor visa to Saudi Arabia?

Tags: visas, price, saudi-arabia

How much do individual and family visitor visa cost to Saudi Arabia?

Comment: It quite likely costs varying amounts depending on the citizenship of the applicants and the country in which they apply for the visa.

Answer (score 9):

> The visa fee is one hundred and eight U.S. dollars ($108.00) for U.S.
>   passport holders; for non-U.S. passport holders the fee is fifty-four
>   U.S. dollars ($54.00) for a single entry and one hundred and
>   thirty-four U.S. dollars ($134.00) for multiple entries.

Requirements of travel visa is [here](http://saudiembassy.net/services/Personal_visit_visa.aspx)

Requirements of family visa is [here](http://saudiembassy.net/services/family_visit_visa.aspx)